# how to remove element.style in css

Tags: css, element

I am using Joomla 1.5.
i am having a page where a cSS  has been added for the title
which is in `<strong></strong>`

I firebug it , it appears as

```
element.style {
color:#666666;
}
```

i dont know of from where it comes from..

but i am having a css applied for the same tag with other color. but it disappeared.
How to remove the element.style globally..

Comment: Firebug shows you exactly which file set this style. Check the CSS properties window after selecting an element that has this style applied.

Comment: ya when i click on the strong tag of that particular page of Joomla1.5 it shows the element.style but it is not showing from where it came from ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to override inline styles from an external stylesheet

```
strong[style] { color: blue !important; }
```

This works in most major browsers, Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE8

It doesn't work (to my knowledge) in IE6 / IE7

Hope this helps.

Comment: i used strong[style] { color: blue !important; }  in my template.css . but still the problem not solved

Answer (score 4):

This code comes from HTML and not from your CSS.

This HTML with generate your element.style:

```
<strong style="color:#666666;">Just text</strong>
```

Element.style, as the name says, its the style defined on element and there is no way to override it. If you do not want that color in that element you must remove/change it on html.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is not always set in HTML. In My case the element.style is empty:

```
element.style {
}
```

It is *not* set in any css and it is *not* set in any html source.
I dont't know where else I should look.

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles are generated from HTML or (more often these days) javascript applying styles after the page had loaded.

Jquery is often a culprit of this, performing animations using css applied directly on the element that overrides your stylesheet.

For instance you may show, then hide a div, leaving a 'display:none' on the element that overrides any naturally cascading CSS that precedes it. This comes up often when you are mixing CSS transitions and media queries with javascript.

Check your JavaScript for any instances of applied styles.

Try using a callback function on the animation to clear styles:

```
$(this).css( "display", "" );
```