# FInding & Editing element.style

Tags: html, css

I am having the hardest time trying to delete a 50px white space. 
This website is run on Joomla 1.5. Below is an image that shows the white space I need to delete. (it's in orange)

Under inspect element using chrome, it comes up with a margin-bottom: 50px but doesn't say were to locate it. Is there any way to find where this is defining this 50px margin?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove element.style in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622372/how-to-remove-element-style-in-css)

Comment: That margin-bottom is inline, meaning it was either written inline (oh god why) or something like javascript added it. You could try adding `margin-bottom: 0!important;` to `.mod_btslideshow_pro` to change it. Inline styles can often be persistent, so you could use Javascript to edit/remove that style attr.

Comment: If you can't see it in css/html code, then it is added by javascript/jquery

Comment: @CollinHenderson: We meet again! Just a heads up, not knowing where it gets set is not a good reason to use !important. This will likely turn into a headache that you'll have to deal with sooner or later anyways. See http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: @Travesty3 Well hey there! !important is pretty harmless if you're being fairly specific about what you want to override. iirc I think inline styles can trump !important even, which is why I offered the JS solution as well.

Comment: @CollinHenderson: Nope, nothing but a more specific `!important` rule will override it.

Comment: @Travesty3 Just did a JSFiddle test, you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's in the html code so you have to go to the source (php) and delete the style tag
It seem to be a slider ? If so, it could be the javascript library who add the style tag to the html

Comment: Found it! It's in the style#.php code. bt slide show has 5-7 styles and each style has a different php code to it. You have do find the correct style your using and edit it. Or i just made it 0.
cho "BTJ('#mod_btslideshow_pro_{$module->id}').css({'margin-bottom':'0px'});\n\t\t";